# Memory allocation for a 2D array in C, using malloc

Tags: arrays, c, pointers, malloc

I am solving a problem that requires me to write a function that returns a pointer to a 2 dimensional array of integers, so I want to understand how memory for a 2D array is allocated using malloc?

I am learning this concept, but I am having a difficult time.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Technically C doesn't really have "multi-dimensional" arrays. All it have are plain arrays, but then each element in turn can then be another arrays. That's how "multi-dimensional" normal arrays work:

```
int arr[X][Y];
```

Here `arr` is an array of `X` elements, each element is an array of `Y` elements.

The most simple and naive way to handle do this nesting for "dynamic" arrays is basically the same: For a simple "one-dimensional" array you have a pointer. So to nest that inside another dynamically created array, you have an array of pointers, or a pointer to a pointer:

```
int **arr;
```

To create memory for it, we first create the outer array:

```
arr = malloc(X * sizeof(*arr));  // sizeof(*arr) is the same as sizeof(int *)
```

Then we need to create each nested array:

```
for (size_t x = 0; x < X; ++x)
{
    arr[x] = malloc(Y * sizeof(*arr[x]));  // sizeof(*arr[x]) is the same as sizeof(int)
}
```

And finally we initialize all the individual array elements:

```
for (size_t x = 0; x < X; ++x)
{
    for (size_t y = 0; y < Y; ++y)
    {
        arr[x][y] = 0;
    }
}
```

There are other ways to create dynamic multi-dimensional arrays, but this is likely what your teacher expect you to create.